# Unable to change the catalog_category_view.xml layout to 1 column in Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, layout

I would like to change the catalog_category_view.xml layout from 2columns-left to 1 column in the custom theme followed below steps.

**Here is the file in the custom theme:**
**`app/design/frontend/VendorName/csutomtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`**

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="columns.top" destination="content" before="-" />
        <move element="category.cms" destination="columns.top" after="-" />
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="false" />
    </body>
</page>
```

After made changes flush cache and verified still not showing the results is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: Can You Please Check in backend category Design Layout ?

Comment: @SavanPatel yes checked. I would like to do it at code level. instead of changing at admin end for each category.

Comment: @NagarajuK there is possibility of it is being override by some third party module. Try to disable all third party modules and check or check on fresh magento.

Comment: Yes @RahulBarot  disabled some 3rd party modules but no luck.